# request variable turns empty in a pdo array

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

this cross-domain ajax post refuses to use my variable in a prepared array.

This is a snippet i use all the time. $userid is available and shows the right value, but as soon as i put it into the execute array it blanks out and throws a "field cannot be empty" error.

```
    $network = $_POST['network'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $content = $_POST['postcontent'];

$sql = "insert into activities(`act_type`, `act_owner`, `act_sender`, `created`, `network`) values (:act_type, :act_owner, :act_sender, :created, :network)";
$conn->save_queries = false;
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':act_type'=>$act_type, ':act_owner'=>$userid, ':act_sender'=>$userid, ':created'=>$date, ':network'=>$network));
```

This is what im now using. it works but i dont like it.

```
$sql = "insert into activities(`act_type`, `act_owner`, `act_sender`, `created`, `network`) values (:act_type, '".$userid."', '".$userid."', :created, '".$network."')";
$conn->save_queries = false;
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':act_type'=>$act_type, ':created'=>$date));
```

I return the values to my ajax call with this, and it returns the correct values

```
//Does not matter if i user request or post, the values are returned.

        $json = json_encode(array(
            'postcontent'=>$_REQUEST['postcontent'],
            'userid'=>$_REQUEST['userid'],
            'network'=>$_REQUEST['network']
        ));
    echo $json;
```

Comment: Is **$act_type** set?

Comment: yep, and read correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: it sent my formData as integers, so i had to take that into concideration on my prepared statement.